# Meteor - Accessing user fields from client

Tags: meteor

I use usernames for new accounts instead of emails. I have recently added a feature that allows users to add their email to subscribe to notifications.

to add emails I use this method on the server:

```
addEmail: function (email) {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
  }
  Roles.addUsersToRoles(Meteor.userId(), 'subscriber');
  Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { email: email } });
}
```

I want this email field to be accessible to the client.
So I tried publishing the user to the client like this.

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find(
      {_id: this.userId},
      {fields: {email: 1}
    });
  }
});
```

Ideally this will publish the current user with it's email to the client.

Here is my client side subscribe: `Meteor.subscribe("userData");`

Now here is my question, How do I access this data (email string) client side? and can this method be used for different fields?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `accounts-password`, all users will have an auto-published `emails` field as seen [here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser). Just to be clear, are you intentionally avoiding this built-in feature?

Comment: So I want users to be able to use the app without providing an email. there is an input box at the bottom of the page that allows users to enter in an email so that they can stay up to date with notifications. 

I will probably replace usernames with emails (for login) in the future. but for this beta version I want to make it as easy as possible for users to start using the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any fields from an existing client/server collection that you selectively publish are typically published to the original Mongo Collection and accessible from there. In this case, `Meteor.user()` or `Meteor.users.find(Meteor.userId())` will return the user collection. `Meteor.user().email` should be available to each client with this field.

Comment: Thanks Adan, calling `Meteor.users.find(Meteor.userId())` worked, and returned this:    

`{"_id":"3ZeujeQJMkjT8anrM","username":"clement","roles":["admin","subscriber"]}`    

Email is missing. Here is what the user looks like in mongo:    
   
`{ "_id" : "3ZeujeQJMkjT8anrM",    ...   "username" : "clement", "roles" : [ "admin", "subscriber" ], "email" : "erwerw" }`   

Everything except the email and password/hash fields were sent to the client.

Comment: figured it out, I needed to specify the custom field using the fields tag: Here is the correct publish function: `Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
      if(!this.userId) return null;
      return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'email':1}});
    });`